didChangeAppLifecycleState in Flutter keeps getting called in a loop
I have this code block:
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  final CameraController? cameraController = _controller;

  // App state changed before we got the chance to initialize.
  if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
    return;
  }

  if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
    cameraController.dispose();
  } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    _initializeCamera();
  }
}

It is similar to the code block provided in the Camera Plugin documentation(https://pub.dev/documentation/camera/latest/) except I handled the camera list inside the _initializeCamera() instead of passing it in as an argument.
The issue I am having is when I was debugging my code, I noticed that this function will keep getting called when I am switching between apps on the phone. During the first time it's called it will dispose the controller as expected, but then it will continue calling itself until binding.dart calls didHaveMemoryPressure() and stops it from calling itself. When I switch back to the app it does fire off the _initializeCamera() and everything works normal. If I didn't put a breakpoint there it would run as if there was no problem.
I guess it works as in it does dispose the controller and reinitialize it like nothing happened, but it doesn't seem normal. Can anyone tell me what's going on here.
Tried setting controller to null with the dispose, and also tried using cameraController.start and .stop but I don't think it made a difference.

May not necessarily indicate a problem with your code but rather how Flutter handles lifecycle state changes. However, the repeated calls could be the result of incorrect handling of the CameraController lifecycle.
Please update didChangeAppLifecycleState() with below code.
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  final CameraController? cameraController = _controller;

  if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
    return;
  }

  if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
    if (cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      cameraController.dispose();
      _controller = null;
    }
  } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    if (_controller == null) {
      _initializeCamera();
    }
  }
}

or
AppLifecycleState? _lastLifecycleState;

@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  final CameraController? cameraController = _controller;

  if (_lastLifecycleState == state) return;

  _lastLifecycleState = state;

  if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
    return;
  }

  switch (state) {
    case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
    case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      if (cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
        cameraController.dispose();
        _controller = null;
      }
      break;

    case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
      if (_controller == null) {
        _initializeCamera();
      }
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}


Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately the code produced the same issue.

I have edited my answer please try another answer I hope it works

I tried it and the problem still persisted. Additionally the new code you provided will fire off the return call in if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isInitialized) before getting to the AppLifecycleState.resumed to start up the camera again.

I was trying to look more into the issue, chatgpt said that it could be the breakpoint which effectively pauses the app at the point where I am switching apps might be the reason why it keeps triggering the AppLifecycleState. I was hesitant to post this because I was unable to find any referencing material to support this and chatgpt has a lot of false info. Does anyone else have an issue where adding breakpoints will cause issues with otherwise good code?
